# wxPython - Cannot catch event from dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a main window with a bunch of widgets. One widget is a combobox for a drop down list. I also have a "Settings" dialog where items can be added to this list. I'm trying to have any changes to the contents of said list generate a custom event "events.EVT_CHANGEDLIST", however my frame does not seem to see this event. I have one other handler for the event, but I make sure to call event.Skip() to allow the event to propagate up. My custom event is as simple as it gets, and I'm sure there is a better way to set it up, but I thought I may build on it in the future. The event is

```
myEVT_CHANGEDLIST = wx.NewEventType()
EVT_CHANGEDLIST = wx.PyEventBinder(myEVT_CHANGEDLIST, 1)

class ChangedAvailableModelsEvent(wx.PyCommandEvent):
    def __init__(self, id):
        evtType = myEVT_CHANGEDLIST
        wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self, evtType, id)
```

Comment: have you tried disabling the first handler to see if its the cause?

Comment: I have, but thanks for the suggestion. I did the same for different issue and it helped reveal I was just forgetting to call Skip()